# How do I trigger a push to a remote server from a GitHub action?

Tags: github, github-actions, push, git-push

I have this remote set up from my local

```
$ git remote -v
dev myuser@mydomain.remote:/home/myuser/maps.git (fetch)
dev myuser@mydomain.remote:/home/myuser/maps.git (push)
```

In my remote repo, I have a hook, ~/maps.git/hooks/post-receive, with

```
# The production directory
TARGET="/var/www/html"

# A temporary directory for deployment
TEMP="/home/myuser/deploy-folder"

# The Git repo
REPO="/home/myuser/maps.git"

# Deploy the content to the temporary directory
mkdir -p $TEMP
#git --work-tree=$TEMP --git-dir=$REPO checkout -f
cd $TEMP
git pull
...
```

What I would like to do is whenever a PR merges into a particular branch (authentication), I would like to trigger a "git push dev" code push to the remote server from a GitHub action.  Not quite sure how to fill in my GitHub action.  I have this

```
name: "Build Dev & Release"
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - "**"
      - ".github/workflows/my-github-action.yml"
    branches:
      - authentication
jobs:
  pusht-to-dev-server:
    ???
```

but not quite sure how to implement the "push-to-dev-server" action.

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, I created this file

```
$ cat .github/workflows/directory-dev.yml 
name: "Chicommons Maps Dev: Build & Release"
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - "**"
      - ".github/workflows/directory-dev.yml"
    branches:
      - authentication 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        persist-credentials: false # otherwise, the token used is the GITHUB_TOKEN, instead of your personal access token.
        fetch-depth: 0 # otherwise, there would be errors pushing refs to the destination repository.
    - name: Push changes
      uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
      with:
        github_url: dev.myremote.com:/home/myusername/maps.git
        github_token: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY }}
        branch: ${{ github.ref }}
```

and I created this environment encrypted secret

[image]

but when I push to my branch (autnentication), I get this error

```
Run ad-m/github-push-action@master 

Push to branch refs/heads/authentication 

Missing input "github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}".
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this would assume `mydomain.remote` is internet-facing (as opposed to on-premise only, [behind a DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing))).

That means GitHub servers (where the GitHub action/workflow is executed) must be able to see and contact `mydomain.remote`.

You can the use the [`github-push-action`](https://github.com/ad-m/github-push-action), initially made to push to a GitHub repository, but that you can change to include your own domain server.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        persist-credentials: false # otherwise, the token used is the GITHUB_TOKEN, instead of your personal access token.
        fetch-depth: 0 # otherwise, there would be errors pushing refs to the destination repository.
    - name: Push changes
      uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
      with:
        github_url: mydomain.remote
        github_token: ${{ secrets.YOURDOMAIN_TOKEN }}
        branch: ${{ github.ref }}
```

Comment: Yup "mydomain.remote" is indeed internet facing.  One question though, where would "secrets.YOURDOMAIN_TOKEN" be stored?  And what username is being used?

Comment: @Dave `secrets.YOURDOMAIN_TOKEN` would be initialized as a [GitHub encrypted secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository). And would serve both as username and password, since the token is tied to a user.

Comment: Thanks.  I added some details to my question showing the encrypted environment secret I created and the full contents of the GitHub action.  When I push to my remote branch, triggering the action,  I get this failure message "Missing input "github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"".  Was I supposed to name my secret "GITHUB_TOKEN"?  I named it DEPLOY

Comment: @Dave it is created for you: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication

Comment: In my actions/permissions section, I have "Allow all actions and reusable workflows " checked.  If this is automatically generated, I'm not understanding why the error message is telling me the GITHUB_TOKEN input is missing.

Comment: @Dave That comes from the [action `start.sh` script](https://github.com/ad-m/github-push-action/blob/9a46ba8d86d3171233e861a4351b1278a2805c83/start.sh#L12-L16). See if [issue 96](https://github.com/ad-m/github-push-action/issues/96#issuecomment-890513303) (and subsequent comments) can clarify why you see that error.